# General relativity: Proof of Lorentz transformation validity for Linearized gravity

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, coordinate-systems, covariance

Wikipedia says that Lorentz transformation is only correct for inertial coordinates. However, I was flipping though Gravitation by Misner et al.

On page 439, it says that for linearized gravity

$$
\eta_{\alpha' \beta'} + h_{\alpha' \beta'}= g_{\alpha' \beta'} = \frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\alpha'}}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^{\beta'}}g_{\mu \nu} = \Lambda^\mu_{\alpha'}\Lambda^\nu_{\beta'}(\eta_{\mu\nu}+ h_{\mu\nu}) = \eta_{\alpha' \beta'} + \Lambda^\mu_{\alpha'}\Lambda^\nu_{\beta'}h_{\mu \nu}
$$
Problem is, I dont understand that this equality is true:
$$
\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial x^{\alpha'}}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial x^{\beta'}}g_{\mu \nu} = \Lambda^\mu_{\alpha'}\Lambda^\nu_{\beta'}(\eta_{\mu\nu}+ h_{\mu\nu})
$$

Can you prove it for us?